# Connecting to microsoft proxy server with authentication from Linux

Tags: linux, proxy

The company I worked for has decided to put in a stupid microsoft proxy server which require authentication.

Windows PCs work (obviously), but I am having trouble from my Linux box. Everything worked fine before they changed from squid to microsoft.

I tried setting the following in ~/.profile

```
export http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy>:8080
export https_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy>:8080
```

Chrome and Firefox just hangs and synaptic package manager says:
Authentication Required

Comment: If things don't work by using the "normal" proxy settings inside the browsers then I suggest you start debugging: sniff web traffic from a MS-Windows and from a linux system and compare the content sent when setting up the authentication.

Comment: A side note: keep in mind however that this has been declared illegal in many states, since it might uncover super secret business secrets of MS. No joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome and firefox has a configuration window for proxy server. why not doing it from there. and for authentication the username should be domain\user instead of user only

Comment: Firefox has a configuration windows for proxy server, chrome uses the system proxy settings.

Comment: @javapenguin if it works please accept this as answer